# Audio stopped working in 11.04

Tags: 11.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, oss

Today, maybe after some automatic updates, my audio stopped to work... Doesn't work anymore both with ALSA (the default one) and Pulseaudio.. So I've tried to install also OSS (doesn't work so I've removed). What can I try to do? :(

Comment: Do you use ubuntu's sourround sound capabilities? They sometimes cause trouble.

Answer (score 2):

My problem with SB Audigy 4 [SB0610] is that it always starts with bad alsamixer settings @ first run after installing ubuntu.

I found out that i have to switch the "Audigy Analog/Digital Output Jack" with the "m" button on the keyb:

[image]

To reach this screen you have to type into the terminal:

```
$ alsamixer
```

Then scroll to the right, and you shall find something like on the picture. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I've reinstalled alsamixer packages.. now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me the other day, and the solution was to make sure nothing was muted by using the command line tool alsamixer. Someone with more experience will likely be able to help you further...